# Apache Camel ProducerTemplate to ignore SSL Certificate Check

Tags: java, ssl, apache-camel

I am consuming SOAP Service using Apache Camel, and the service is hosted on a Self Signed certificate for the development purposes.

I tried importing the certificate to a keystore but failed, since the certificate doesn't have a valid CN.

I am trying to either ignore the certificate error or trust all certificates. How do i do it using producerTemplate.

```
        Exchange exchangeRequest = producerTemplate.request(endpoint,
            new Processor() {
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    exchange.getIn().setBody(payload);
                    if (headermap != null && headermap.size() > 0) {
                        exchange.getIn().setHeaders(headermap);
                    }
                    if (soapHeader != null && !soapHeader.equals("")) {
                        exchange.getIn()
                                .setHeader(
                                        SpringWebserviceConstants.SPRING_WS_SOAP_HEADER,
                                        soapHeader);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have  you looked at : https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/camel-users/201108.mbox/%3CCAF55cLt++0n-UKTXyNvJsO=FLFw-isQ5pNNzS0-2HumApJpkzg@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: But the httpClientConfigurer option is not available for Spring-ws component. Only sslContextParameters is available and it requires a keystore to it.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to use [Samy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1900006/samy) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39114276/4137546) for consumer, but it not works. This is client-side variation for trustAllCerts (function style, because i am using Talend Open Studio):

```
java.util.function.Consumer<org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean> trustAllCerts = sfb -> {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts_ = new TrustManager[] {
        new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {    return null;}
            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {}
            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) throws CertificateException {}
        }
    };
    org.apache.cxf.Bus theBus = org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusFactory.getThreadDefaultBus();
    ((FactoryBeanListenerManager)theBus.getExtension(FactoryBeanListenerManager.class))
    .addListener((evnt, sfb_, args) -> {
        if (evnt != org.apache.cxf.service.factory.FactoryBeanListener.Event.CLIENT_CREATED) return;
        TLSClientParameters tlsParams = new TLSClientParameters();
        tlsParams.setTrustManagers(trustAllCerts_);
        tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);
        WebClient.getConfig((WebClient)args[0]).getHttpConduit().setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);
    });
    sfb.setBus(theBus);
};
```